# Function of polygonplots does not plot all polygons

Tags: maple, polygons

Could anyone explain to me why my Maple-Code does not work properly?

```
 with(plots):
 plotSet := proc(M) 
 local n::posint, dispM; 
 n := nops({M}); 
 dispM := map(i -> 
                  polygonplot([[M[i], 0], [M[i+1], 0], [M[i+1], 1], [M[i], 1]], 
                  color = red),
              [$1 .. n]);
 display(dispM);
 end proc;
```

If I want to plot following:

```
 plotSet([0, 1/5], [2/5, 3/5]);
```

Maple just plots the first rectangle. Why doesn't it plot all rectangles?

Comment: Could you list for me exactly what you intend as the four vertices for each rectangle? The fact that you make the second coordinate 0 or 1 in your procedure is throwing me off.

Comment: This is not a mathematical question, and you should ask on StackOverflow or MaplePrimes instead.

Comment: @CarlLove I intent to plot rectangles with height 1 and width b-a of a given list of intervals [a, b].

Comment: Okay, I updated the Answer with working procedures.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that since you only declared one argument, Maple only sees one argument. That is, **M** is simply **[0, 1/5]**. Extra arguments are by default ignored by Maple procedures. You get around this by declaring **M** to be a sequence via

```
plotSet:= proc(M::seq(list))
```

But after that there are other problems with your procedure. See my comment.

**Update**: Make the procedure thus:

```
plotSet:= proc(M::seq(list)) 
local n::posint, dispM; 
     n:= nops({M}); 
     dispM:= map(i -> 
          plots:-polygonplot([[M[i][1], 0], [M[i][2], 0], [M[i][2], 1], [M[i][1], 1]], 
               color = red),
          [$1 .. n]);
     plots:-display(dispM);
end proc;
```

A better procedure is

```
plotSet:= proc(M::seq(list))
local m::list;
     plots:-display([
          seq(
               plots:-polygonplot(
                    [[m[1],0], [m[2],0], [m[2],1], [m[1],1]],
                    color= red
               ),
               m in M
          )
      ])
end proc:
```

Comment: Well, does my procedure work for you???? It's rude to not comment and also not vote.